# How to Call a Bool Function on Button Click Event

Tags: c#

I am trying to call a bool type function from button click but facing error

```
"mybtn_Click(object, System.EventArgs)' has the wrong return type"
```

I need to return false bcoz I am working on a modal popup and after function completion popup getting closed.

My function is :-

```
protected bool btnforgotpwd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //code
   return false;
}
```

Comment: It has to have a return type of `void` to match the buttons event delegate.  Why do you have a `bool` return type in the first place?

Comment: Please share some code with us.

Comment: There is no piece of code that can *read* and make use of that `bool` value if the function is only being used as an event handler.

Comment: Event handlers are `void`, they don't return anything.  What are you trying to accomplish here?  Nothing in the framework would *expect* an event handler to return anything.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, the delegate type that the click event is using
returns `void` I.e., it returns absolutely nothing.

So, what I would do is create a separate function which returns a bool to do the work of the click handler. Then obviously, you call this new bool-returning function from the click handler.

```
protected void btnforgotpwd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoForgotPassword();
}

protected bool DoForgotPassword()
{
    //Do any work here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the function call inside the handler.

Double click your `mybtn` button in the designer, Visual Studio will build the following function:

```
void mybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Function will be empty
}
```

Then, put your function inside that

```
void mybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var boolValue = btnforgotpwd_Click(sender, e);
    // Now use your bool
}
```

You can read up on events on MSDN, for example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dacysss4(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the method `mybtn_Click` its return type is `void` but you return a string or other object.

```
   protected void mybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
      return obj;   // you should not have a return statement inside
   }
```